# How do you web scrape nested table using PHP?

Tags: php, html

**Backstory**
First off, I have used PHP to read email and extract out the HTML attachment which later on I stored in a PHP variable.

Now the problem I am facing is that I am trying to extract out information from the HTML in a nested table and hoping to convert to some sort of array so that I can store in SQL.

May I know if there are solutions for this? As I have tried finding but to no avail.

**Example**

```
<html>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <p>hi</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

I want to locate the nearest table tag where "hi" is located so that I can get all the information from that table

**Stuff I have tried**

I have tried using simple HTML DOM but I guess the HTML file that I tried scraping was too large that it causes memory issues.

```
include('./simple_html_dom.php');

/* Parse the HTML, stored as a string in $woString */ <br>
$html = str_get_html($worksOrder); 

/* Locate the ultimate grandfather table id that wraps all his generation */<br>
$messytables = $html->find('table');

print_r($messytables);
```

Comment: I don't know this library, but in DOM you could find the p tag and then use something like parentNode().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using simple HTML DOM, this uses DOMDocument and XPath to find the elements.

This draws on the answer [XPath to find nearest ancestor element that contains an element that has an attribute with a certain value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005370/xpath-to-find-nearest-ancestor-element-that-contains-an-element-that-has-an-attr) to locate the `<table>` tags that enclose the `<p>` tags which have `hi` in it.  As there are a few levels of enclosing `<table>` tags, it then uses `last()` (from [XSLT getting last element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459132/xslt-getting-last-element)) to find the innermost enclosing `<table>`...

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc = new DOMDOcument();
$doc->loadHTML( $worksOrder );
$xp = new DOMXPath($doc);

$table = $xp->query('(//ancestor::table[descendant::p="hi"])[last()]');

echo $doc->saveHTML($table[0]);
```

The last line is just to display the data, you can just start with `$table[0]` and fetch the data as needed.

This outputs with your test data...

```
<table><tr>
<td>
                            <p>hi</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr></table>
```